# How do I reuse complex types accross different services?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have 2 separate java services that use a complex type that is a exactly the same but takes an  email object as a parameter like:

```
class Email{
     Description{get;}
     Address{get;}
}
```

The services look something like this:

emailBasketBallTeam(email);
emailTennisTeam(email);

Is there a way that I can specify a contract for the email object or somehow reuse the email object in different services despite them being in completely different namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `wsdl /sharetypes`, you need to consume one service at a time, but you can re-use types from existing assemblies.

With `svcutil`, you can use the /reference switch. I believe you can also do this in the IDE in the designer.